# Deleting all content down from the second horizontal line in a document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to create a script to delete all text/content downwards from a page. Below you can see the current document.

[image]

Currently, I have the script set-up so that it deletes everything down and including from a text of, "STARTHERE". However, I want it to delete down from the second horizontal line in the image, however, not including the line.

1. Any ideas on how to delete down from the second horizontal line?
2. What does deleteText startOffset and endOffsetInclusive actually mean? Is it like a line number or?

Previous Script:

```
function removeText() {
    var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    var rangeElement = body.editAsText();
    var start = "STARTHERE";
    var end = "ENDHERE";
    var rangeElement1 = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText(start);
    var rangeElement2 = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText(end);
    if (rangeElement1.isPartial()) {
       var startOffset = rangeElement1.getStartOffset();
       var endOffset = rangeElement2.getEndOffsetInclusive();
       rangeElement1.getElement().asText().deleteText(startOffset,endOffset);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change your approach completely, because `findText` only finds text, and a horizontal line is not text; it is a special type of document element, [HorizontalRule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/horizontal-rule).

(Since you asked: startOffset and endOffsetInclusive are character counts within an element; e.g., if the text "red" is found in a paragraph that consists of "A big red dog", then startOffset is 6 and endOffset is 9. None of this helps here)

Here is my approach: loop over the Paragraph elements, looking for those that contain a HorizontalRule element (with [`findElement`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#findElement(ElementType)) method). Once we found two such paragraphs, delete all subsequent ones.

There is a catch in that Apps Script can't delete the last paragraph of a document; for this reason I append empty paragraph ahead of time, and do not delete it.

```
function removeAfterSecondLine() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.appendParagraph('');
  var para = body.getParagraphs();
  var ruleCount = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < para.length - 1; i++) {
    if (ruleCount >= 2) {
      body.removeChild(para[i]);
    }
    else if (para[i].findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.HORIZONTAL_RULE)) {
      ruleCount++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't expecting an actual answer, just an approach to take. Once again, thank you so much for making my life easier!