# Adding and deleting content between two points on a document

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I currently have a document, with help from StackOverflow users already, that randomly generates questions, adds it to the end of a document, and then has the ability to delete all the questions posted. This is based on deleting everything under a horizontal rule.

Link to GDrive containing example document & code: [LINK TO GDRIVE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LpDeWu6ICEQpwqTciYL8CQeR0U1mxBvg?usp=sharing)

You can also see what it currently does here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF6Kr.jpg

However, I now want to only want to add content after a certain point in the document, as well as only delete content between two certain points. You can see the two horizontal rules in an image below in which I want to add/delete 
content.

[image]

The first horizontal rule in the picture is the third horizontal rule in the document.

Has anyone got any ideas how I can delete and add content between those two points? I've tried using child index's but failed miserably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [Deleting all content down from the second horizontal line in a document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47291817) so I adapt the solutions. First function deletes the paragraphs between the 3rd and 4th line. It counts horizontal lines as we loop through paragraphs. When the count reaches 3, start deleting subsequent paragraphs. When it exceeds 3, stop the loop.

```
function deleteFrom3to4() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.appendParagraph('');
  var para = body.getParagraphs();
  var ruleCount = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < para.length - 1; i++) {
    if (para[i].findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.HORIZONTAL_RULE)) {
      ruleCount++;
    }
    else if (ruleCount == 3) {
      body.removeChild(para[i]);
    }
    if (ruleCount > 3) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

And this one inserts a paragraph after the 3rd horizontal line. Again, it loops until the 3rd line is found; inserts a paragraph after it (expressed by `body.getChildIndex(para[i]) + 1` child index) and stops.

```
function insertAfter3() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.appendParagraph('');
  var para = body.getParagraphs();
  var ruleCount = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < para.length - 1; i++) {
    if (para[i].findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.HORIZONTAL_RULE)) {
      ruleCount++;
    }
    if (ruleCount == 3) {
      body.insertParagraph(body.getChildIndex(para[i]) + 1, "Here is a new paragraph");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just returned home from a weekend away, so sorry for late comment. This works perfectly thanks :)